Purpose of USB eToken for storing EV code signing certificate's private key, when certificate is delivered via a download link?
A while ago I purchased code signing EV certificate from DigiCert. I already owned a USB eToken so I selected a delivery method where I download it from their website. The order required me to attach a CSR, which I generated via their Certificate Utility for Windows. At no point was there any interaction using the existing hardware eToken and it was not even plugged in so I know that the private key must have been stored on the Windows machine, which generated the CSR and not on the USB eToken.
When they sent me the download links, I simply imported them into their DigiCert Certificate Utility. Meaning that the certificate and private key now both reside on my PC, not on my USB eToken.
It seems I don't even require the eToken device to sign the code, which makes me wonder, what was the point of the eToken in the first place for this specific delivery method? Was I supposed to export the private key and cert and import it into the USB eToken and then delete it from my machine? Assuming the only job eToken has is to store a private key that can't be exported easily, why is there even an option to deliver an EV certificate via a download link and why was I able to generate CSR with a utility program without attaching the USB eToken?

"What was the point of the eToken in the first place for this specific delivery method?" - The eToken is more likely to last longer than a single installation of an operating system.


Assuming the only job eToken has is to store a private key that can't be exported easily, why is there even an option to deliver an EV certificate via a download link

The certificate is not the private key. It's a signed version of the public key. Delivery method of the certificate therefore has no relationship with where or how the private key is stored.

why was I able to generate CSR with a utility program without attaching the USB eToken?

There's nothing in the CSR that would indicate where the private key was generated. (And the DigiCert app is a general purpose tool; it's not specifically limited to eToken use.)
Some hardware tokens support "key attestation", where the device itself produces a CSR with its own signature as proof that the private key was indeed generated on-device, and some CAs require such attestations. For example, Sectigo – if I remember correctly – supports CSR-based issuance of EV certificates only with very specific tokens (Yubikey mostly), as those are the only ones that support key attestation.
But other CAs, such as DigiCert apparently, might just leave it as a responsibility of the user to make sure they generate the key securely.
Here's what the CA/B Forum rules say about it:

16 Data Security
(4) CAs SHALL ensure that the Subscriber’s private key is generated, stored and used in a crypto module that meets or exceeds the requirements of FIPS 140-2 level 2.Acceptable methods of satisfying this requirement include (but are not limited to) the following:

a. The CA ships a suitable hardware crypto module, with a preinstalled key pair, in the form of a smartcard or USB device or similar;
b. The Subscriber counter-signs certificate requests that can be verified by using a manufacturer’s certificate indicating that the key is managed in a suitable hardware module;
c. The Subscriber provides a suitable IT audit indicating that its operating environment achieves a level of security at least equivalent to that of FIPS 140-2 level 2


So while Sectigo for example limits itself to options a) or b), perhaps the "(but are not limited to)" gives DigiCert enough freedom to just accept any CSR and say "customer signed a contract that requires them to store it securely, so it's not our problem anymore".

I find it hard to read the quoted section of the CA/B rules as allowing CAs to simply delegate the whole problem to the customer (especially given the mention of an "IT audit"). OTOH, I suspect that nobody really cares about EVs now that they no longer cause browsers to display special UX, so maybe there's no interest (on the browser side) in actually having this argument.

@Kevin These are code-signing certificates, which are generally under the purview of the OS, not a browser. Specifically, Microsoft requires EV certificates for drivers. What a browser does or does not do with EV certs isn't all that relevant here.


Was I supposed to export the private key and cert and import it into the USB eToken and then delete it from my machine?

This would have been one possible way to set up the eToken, but not necessarily the optimal way.
When generating a CSR for an eToken with maximum security in mind, it should ideally be done using an eToken-aware tool, with the token plugged in. This allows the CSR generation to happen inside the token, so the private key is also created within the token and will never leave the token during the certificate's entire lifetime.
However, maximum security may require a compromise in terms of availability: if the token is damaged, and the private key is locked inside the token, there can be no backup of the private key, and so a new certificate will need to be created.
By allowing the creation of eToken-compatible certificates without involving the actual token, the CA makes it possible for you to import the same private key to two or more eTokens, allowing for easy replacement if a single eToken fails. The flip side is, you will have to ensure the security of the key generation and eToken set-up process. The recommended way would be to do this on an airgapped system that can be fully wiped once the eToken(s) have been tested and found to be good.
Neither the CSR nor the resulting certificate needs to be kept secret: in fact, your customers will need a copy of the certificate in order to be able to validate the code signatures you generate using the private key. This is why delivering the certificate via a download link is not an issue.
Since the CA never gets your private key, you know for sure that the CA cannot possibly leak it to anyone.
